# Types for static property of styled-components element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

How can I type a styled-component element that has a static property?

```js
interface IMyList {
  Item: ThemedStyledFunction<"li", any>;
}

const MyList: IMyList = styled.ul`
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
`;

MyList.Item = styled.li`
  display: block;
  padding-left: 16px;
  color: rebeccapurple;
`;

// Usage
type TUser = {
    name: string;
    age: number
}

export default function Users(data: TUser[]) {
    return (
        <List>
            {data.map(user => {
                <List.Item>
                    <span className="name">{ user.name }</span>
                    <span className="age">{ user.age }</span>
                </List.Item>
            })}
        </List>
    );
}
```

The above throws me `Property 'Item' is missing in type 'String & StyledComponentBase<"ul", any, {}, never>' but required in type 'IMyList'.ts(2741)` for "MyList" and `Property 'attrs' is missing in type 'String & StyledComponentBase<"li", any, {}, never>' but required in type 'ThemedStyledFunction<"li", any, {}, never>'.ts(2741)` for "MyList.Item".

Comment: Can you share whole example? Error is because here: const MyList: IMyList you don't have property Item.

Comment: @RTW Ok, I've added an example on how I pretend to use it.

Comment: here it is, there is nothing needed to be typed more for your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-e2v6k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you, I know I can separate Item from List, just the way you did. But I want to be able to add the Item as a "static" prop of List using BEM Concepts (as exposed here https://tech.decisiv.com/structuring-our-styled-components-part-i-2bf21fa64b28#75f9) and type it accordingly.